# Issue with Clob and string

Tags: java, jpa

I'm working on a very old Java software (1.8).

There is an `Entity` mapped to Oracle. One field (payload named) is `CLOB` on Oracle; this stores a XML. On the Entity this field is mapped as `String`.

If I use Glassfish 3.5 as App Server, **it works everytime.**

If I use same code with Tomcat 8.5 as server, I have a strange behaviour.

The entity, only with some XML, on `getPayload()` returns an empty string on some XML. There is no reason (character set, lenght, etc etc etc). On several other it returns the right XML.

So, I changed the type to `CLOB` on Entity et voilà, I can get every XML I want.

I know it's difficult to answer... but... why?

Comment: When you run it on Tomcat are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink (like in Glassfish)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Hibernate. Another solution: upgraded ODBC driver and it works.